# jest TouchEvent TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I am writing a test for a function `MyFuntion` and that calls another function `sendTouchEvent` that instantiates a TouchEvent.

```js
function sendTouchEvent(element, eventType) {  
  const touch = new Touch({
      ...
  });

  const touchEvent = new TouchEvent(eventType, {
      ...
  });

  element.dispatchEvent(touchEvent);
}
```

My test is like this:

```js
const { test, expect } = require("@jest/globals");
const fs = require('fs');
const chrome = require("sinon-chrome");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const dom = new JSDOM()
global.document = dom.window.document
global.window = dom.window
global.chrome = chrome
global.MutationObserver = class {
    constructor(callback) {}
    disconnect() {}
    observe(element, initObject) {}
};

jest.dontMock('jquery');
$ = jQuery = require("jquery");
global.$ = $
global.jQuery = jQuery

const content = require("../content");
const data = require("./fixtures/data.json");

test("get data", () => {
    const mod = rewire("../content")
    mod.__set__('data', data) // mocking json data
    var el = document.createElement("div")
    el.innerHTML = html_str; // loaded before with fs.readFileSync
    
    expect(content.MyFunction(el)).toBe({})
})
```

My jest.setup.js file is like this:

```js
$ = require("jquery");
global.$ = $;
global.window.$ = $;
```

And I am getting this error:

```js
    TypeError: $ is not a function

      207 |   });
      208 |
    > 209 |   const touchEvent = new TouchEvent(eventType, {
          |                                                ^
      210 |       cancelable: true,
      211 |       bubbles: true,
      212 |       touches: [touch],

      at extension/content.js:209:48
      at Object.<anonymous> (extension/content.js:411:4)
      at Object.load (node_modules/rewire/lib/moduleEnv.js:55:18)
      at internalRewire (node_modules/rewire/lib/rewire.js:49:15)
      at rewire (node_modules/rewire/lib/index.js:11:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (extension/tests/content.test.js:26:17)
```

I tried to mock the `sendTouchEvent` function already, but it doesn't work. Also tried to inject `$` using rewire `mod.__set__`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was the `rewire` lib. For some reason, it was messing with the window's events. I remove it and change my code to be able to mock `data` variable without `rewire`